# how to push a new view controller from UITableView object cell

Tags: uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2, pushviewcontroller

i am trying to create a UITableView application on Xcode 4.2.
i just want each cells (ex. Cali) to push a new ViewController when its pushed

The issue I'm running into is whenever i press the cells its not pushing the new view controller

MY TableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Adam : UITableViewController 
{
    NSMutableArray *states;
}

@end
```

My Tableviewcontroller.m

```
#import "Adam.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation Adam


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    states = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
              @"cali",
              @"ohio",
              nil];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [states count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [cellLabel setText:[states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([[states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"cali"])

    { 
        ViewController *cali = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cali" bundle:nil]; 
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:cali animated:YES];

    }
}

@end
```

Comment: What issue are you running into? If you set a breakpoint in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, does it get there?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. but i just updated my question

Comment: np.  So does it got into the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: sorry I'm kinda new to this, what do u mean by into the method. i did not code anything in the AppDelegate

Comment: Put a log message or breakpoint into didSelectRowAtIndexPath to see if the program runs that when you touch a cell.

Comment: Good.  Now how about inside the enclosed if statement?

Comment: //the if statement gave me 5 threads  UITableView_selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegat:] 0x000a171d <+1164> mov 0x6098f6(%edi),%eax //this is in thread 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cali.title = [states objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cali animated:YES];
```